# Understanding Azure App Service Metrics about garbage collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection

I am having a hard time understanding these App Service metrics.

Requests seems to be the average number of requests per minute. But am I really getting thousands of Gen 1 and Gen 2 GCs every minute?

[Azure App Service metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq7X4.png)

Are GG numbers too high for a web app that is only getting 220 requests per minute? Can this high number of GCs explain why my requests times are fluctuating between 250 ms to 3 seconds?